# Installing Findbugs plugin for MyEclipse

Tags: eclipse

I am trying to install Findbugs plugin for MyEclipse 6.0.1 using follwing steps:

In Eclipse, click on Help -> Software Update -> Find and Install...
Choose the Search for new features to install option, and click Next.
Click New Remote Site.
Enter the following:
Name: FindBugs update site
URL: one of the following (note: no final slash on the url)
http://findbugs.cs.umd.edu/eclipse for official releases and click OK.
"FindBugs update site" should appear under Sites to include in search. 
Click the checkbox next to it to select it, and click Finish.

As soon as I click Finish eclipse shows me error saying "No features found on selected sites".
Can anyone plz tell me how should I proceed for Findbugs plugin inatallation in MyEclipse v6.0.1.

Comment: That looks like quite an old version of MyEclipse.  Do you know what version of Eclipse that corresponds to?  The Findbugs plugin page says that it is primarily tested with Eclipse 3.3 and 3.4.

Comment: I have myeclipse 6.0.1 which is higher that 3.x as per Findbug plugin page. So ideally it should work..not sure why it is not working

Comment: I think MyEclipse versions are not the same as Eclipse versions.  MyEclipse is Eclipse plus other plugins.  In Help -> About you should be able to see the Eclipse Platform version.

Comment: This is what it shows there:                                       MyEclipse Enterprise Workbench

Version: 6.0.1 GA
Build id: 6.0.1-GA-200710

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MyEclipse 6.6 is based on eclipse 3.3, so I assume 6.0 is also based on eclipse 3.3. That version of MyEclipse is now unsupported. However, you might be able to download the Findbugs plugin from [here](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/downloads.html) (which also list several update sites) and install it manually. I don't recall how to add plugins manually to eclipse 3.3 but there is probably a section in the help that comes with MyEclipse.